# Why is the j-invariant a modular function but not a modular form?

Tags: modular-forms

I read that the j-invariant is a modular *function* but not a modular *form*. This is confusing, because the j-invariant doesn't have poles in the upper half plane. What is the difference between modular functions and modular forms anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An important defining constraint for modular forms is boundedness as ${\rm Im}(\tau) \to \infty$.  To see that this is not true of the $j$-function, from its $q$-expansion
$$
j(q) = \frac{1}{q} + 744 + 196884q + 21493760q^2 + \cdots
$$
where $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$ for $\tau = x + iy$ with $y > 0$, so $|q| = e^{-2\pi y}$ and $|1/q| = e^{2\pi y}$, we have $|j(q)| \to \infty$ as ${\rm Im}(\tau) \to \infty$.

Because the $j$-function is an ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$-invariant function, it resembles a modular form of weight $0$ if you ignore the boundedness condition for modular forms. And it certainly is not a modular form of weight $0$ because the modular forms of weight $0$ are constant functions.

Comment: So are modular *functions* allowed to have poles in the upper half plane, or do they have to be holomorphic in H as well?

Comment: @ZongshuWu  what references have you read about modular functions (and modular forms)?

Comment: I have read wikipedia and wolfram mathworld and stuff like that. They say that poles are allowed except I haven't actually seen any modular functions with poles on H so I'm confused...

Comment: @ZongshuWu  please consult some actual *books* on these topics if you want to learn about these concepts.  Wikipedia and Mathworld are not a serious way to learn something well the first time.